# How can I replace characterScale.x = -1 with transform.Rotate (0f, 180f, 0f) in this context, without it being executed every frame?

Tags: c#, replace

I am very new to coding video games so I have been using a lot on online tutorials to assist me with making a basic platformer/shooter. In order for my character to be able to shoot in both directions, I need the sprite as well as it's child "FirePoint" to flip. How can I flip my character and it's children whenever the Horizontal value = -1 without the same command being executed every frame.

Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpforce;
    private float moveInput;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    private int extraJumps;
    public int extraJumpsValue;

    public Animator animator;
    void Start()
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);


    }
    void Update()
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", moveInput);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;
            extraJumps--;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;
        }
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
        }
        Vector3 characterScale = transform.localScale;
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            characterScale.x = -1;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            characterScale.x = 1;
        }
        transform.localScale = characterScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want to know how to use `Rotate` instead of scale (which seems to be asked by the title), or whether you mainly want to not execute it on every frame (which is what I understand from the question text)?

Comment: Sorry I don't know if this is how I'm supposed to reply on stack overflow. I am asking how i can get the ```Rotate``` to be not executed in every frame in this context.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid doing it on every frame? I am asking because it could make a difference whether it causes a bug, or whether you have performance concerns. If it is for performance reasons, the difference would likely be negligible. Is there a different problem that you actually want to solve, where you think that this might be the cause?

Comment: @RaimundKrämer I don't want it to activate every frame because it causes the sprite to constantly flip back and forth every frame when moving to the left.

Comment: What does the animator do when you set the float `"Horizontal"`? I don't see from the code alone why the sprite should continue flipping back and forth. Maybe the animator and the code try to achieve the same thing, and that results in this behavior? If that is the case, it is possible that if it were not called every frame it would still not behave as intended. Can you add a screenshot of your animation state machine?

Comment: With the screenshot of the animation state machine, maybe an answer will be possible, but independently from that I would recommend to update the title and question to more specifically describe the actual problem, which is the sprite flipping back and forth.